# Involutions in $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, involutions

$\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}$An **involution in a category** is a functor $\mathbf{B}\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathcal{C}$, corresponding precisely to an object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ together with a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,X)$, determining morphisms $\mathrm{id}_X\colon X\to X$ and $\sigma\colon X\to X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $\sigma\circ\sigma=\mathrm{id}_X$.

For example, when $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{B}A$ with $A$ a monoid, we recover the notion of an **involuntory element in $A$**, which is an element $a\in A$ such that $a^2=1_A$.

For bicategories, things get more interesting: we should replace the equality $\sigma\circ\sigma=\mathrm{id}_X$ with a $2$-isomorphism $\tau\colon\sigma\circ\sigma\to\id_X$ (an "**involutor**"), which should satisfy coherence conditions of the form "all compositions from $\sigma^n$ to $\id_X$ are the same"; e.g. the two compositions
\begin{gather*}
(\sigma\circ\sigma)\circ\sigma\overset{\tau\star\id}{\Rightarrow}\id_X\circ\sigma\overset{\lambda_\sigma}{\Rightarrow}\sigma\\
(\sigma\circ\sigma)\circ\sigma\overset{\alpha_{\sigma,\sigma,\sigma}}{\Rightarrow}\sigma\circ(\sigma\circ\sigma)\overset{\id\star\tau}{\Rightarrow}\id_X\circ\sigma\overset{\rho_\sigma}{\Rightarrow}\sigma
\end{gather*}
are the same, as are the ones $\sigma^4\Rightarrow\sigma$ built with associators, unitors, and involutors.

For bicategories which happen to be the delooping of a monoidal category, we obtain the notion of an **involutory object in a monoidal category**, coming with a coherent isomorphism of the form $A\otimes A\overset{\sim}{\dashrightarrow}A$. (Possibility: for braided/symmetric monoidal categories, do we require "involutors" to be compatible with braidings?)

---

**Question.** Is there a notion of involution in an $\infty$-category, coming with all the associated homotopy coherence data ("involutors", "higher involutors", etc.)?

Comment: The correct notion of object with (coherent) involution (i.e. $C_2$ action) in an $\infty$-category is still a functor $BC_2\to \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between your first question and the other questions that come after

Comment: @AchimKrause Thanks, Achim!

Comment: @DenisNardin I was thinking about the relation via deloopings, but it's probably better to ask it as a separate question. I split the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404266).